Recent movie about alien invaders
About a year ago I was watching a trailer about a movie in which some spider formed aliens were invading the earth.
There is a scene I remember almost clearly: 
It was night, and there were massive lightning storms happening. The sky was also cloudy or the air was very foggy, since I don't remember seeing anything other than the alien's shape. The giant spider formed being was standing in the far distance, behind the clouds ( and it was giant, maybe bigger than Godzilla ). Multiple lightning were happening, that allowed the audience get a glimpse of the alient's size and figure.
Additional info

Year: Very recent, after 2010 
Color: Colored 
Genre: Horror 
Language: English
Type: VFX
Hollywood production
Source of trailer: Mojo watch list ( supposed to be top horror list of the year )


Could be several including Godzilla from 2014, Cloverfield from 2008, The Mist from 2014

It could be the last one, since Godzilla has no spider shape and the cloverfield is before 2010...

Godzilla does have a Spider shape monster...perhaps you're thinking of the earlier Godzilla.

I watched the Godzilla movie though, but you are right. Although it wasn't this movie, since the monster was bigger than those.

"Source of trailer: Mojo watch list ( supposed to be top horror list of the year )". A good start would be to try to find it there.

Sounds like the remake of War of the Worlds, but the timing of when the movie came out would be wrong.

Welcome to Movies.SE! We have a minimum requirement for ID questions on this site. Do you remember when/where/how you watched this movie? What language was it in? Was it an American production, or from a different country? Was it real life or animated? We'll need answers to these questions to help us track down an answer to this question.  If you have this information, please edit it into your question.

I think it is the trailer of the second season of Netflix's Stranger Things (2016):
Trailer (scrolled to the scene described in the question):



The spider alien from the trailer:


This was my first thought too actually.  But I'm not sure if the watch list would apply to TV shows, what they meant by aliens, and the fact that it's a "horror".

@JMac I totally agree. I too had doubts giving that OP said movie not serie. But thought that a trailer is not enough proof for the movie assumption. And the scene description fits that trailer scene perfectly. Also all the informations giving by OP fit except for the "movie" part which as I said not well proven. BTW Stranger Things has the Horror tag.

@JMac ... and my assumption was right.
